# Memory issue in custom ListView on back pressed

Tags: android, performance, listview, memory, out-of-memory

I'm developing an android app. And i have a `custom list view` with images , I'm using `Imageloader` class to get avatar image with `LazyLoading`; it was working fine. But now i have added paging to it and now after a 2nd page loads and when i press back button , it'll give this strange green colored error on `Log cat` , any suggestions and help would be highly appreciate.

**Here is the error message:**

```
11-20 14:00:35.260: E/dalvikvm-heap(17158): Out of memory on a 14745616-byte allocation.
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158): "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41147508 self=0x411378c8
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   | sysTid=17158 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074782000
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   | schedstat=( 13252161232 2564002723 28839 ) utm=1095 stm=230 core=3
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:476)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:120)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:110)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:587)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:660)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:685)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
11-20 14:00:35.260: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at com.pichit.ProfileOverviewFragment.onCreateView(ProfileOverviewFragment.java:57)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1478)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:450)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5293)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2606)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2644)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1269)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1008)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:775)
11-20 14:00:35.265: I/dalvikvm(17158):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: it occurs because of high resolution of images which is set to bitmap may be..

Comment: are you using ViewHolder pattern in your list adapter?

Comment: @  Veaceslav Gaidarji. NO i'm not using view Holder pattern. would you think it would work if i do?

Answer (score 0):

this error occur coz your images are too heavy.
You should scale your images to smaller size and then load the image to list view and don't forget to make list view and adapter instance to null in onDestroy() method.

Answer (score 0):

use the best practices for listview and bitmaps handling, as sugegsted by google:

- [**the world of listview**](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html)
- [**handling bitmaps**](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html)